# Print out file content after upload, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

EDIT: I solved it. I wrote:

```
$scope.result = data
```

In the success-area.

I have a form that you can upload files. I'm using angular-file-upload model that I've found at github: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

The upload works perfect. However, after I've uploaded the file, I want to return the file contents, and print it out at the site, but I don't now how to bind the file to the $scope.

Here is my controler:

```
as.controller('Marketing', function($scope, $http, $upload)
    {
        $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
            var file = $files[0];
            if (file.type.indexOf('image') == -1) {
                $scope.error = 'image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.'            
            }
            if (file.size > 2097152){
                $scope.error ='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
            }     
            $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                url: 'partials/result.php',
                data: {},
                file: file,
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my PHP:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if(($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br/></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br/>\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Marketing">
<form class="well form-search" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" >
</form>

<pre ng-model="result">
    {{result}}
</pre>

</div>
```

As you can see, I want to bind the content to the $scope.result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have your files in the app, you just have to bind them to the `$scope`

```
as.controller('Marketing', function($scope, $http, $upload)
    {
        $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
            var file = $files[0];
            if (file.type.indexOf('image') == -1) {
                $scope.error = 'image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.'            
            }
            if (file.size > 2097152){
                $scope.error ='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
            }     
            $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                url: 'partials/result.php',
                data: {},
                file: file,
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                // This is the file you've just successfully uploaded
                $scope.file = file

            });
        }
    });
```